# Handling incoming JSON data to PHP server

Tags: php, json, wordpress, google-sheets

I want to create a function that acts as an HTTP API endpoint to receive notifications whenever a google sheet is updated. When this notification is received, a PHP function would trigger, requesting data from an external data source (Through a GET request). Can anyone point me to a resource to implement this?

example input:

```
{
'Notification_type' : 'row_added'
}
```

Example function psuedocode:

```
function refresh_data()
{
    $spreadsheet_rows = array of spreadsheet rows expressed in JSON
    for each row in $spreadsheet_rows
         insert/update row in mySQL database
}
```

to summarize, I would like an external service to send a notification to my PHP server whenever a spreadsheet on google sheets is updated, and trigger a PHP function on the server upon receiving the notification.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a normal PHP file and get the JSON with [php://input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input).

To decode the JSON you need to use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode).

So, something like this:

```
<?php

if (getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'GET') {
    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($json);
    // .... processing data ....
}
```

You should probably include some error detection.